# accessing html select element which is inside table td

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html snippet

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><select name="day">
        </select></td>
        <td><select name="time">
        </select></td>
        <td><select name="closed" onchange="dosomething(this)">
        </select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When i change something on , then i would like to get a handle to  and do some operation on it. How do i get a handle to  in javascript?

```
function closedChanged(object)
{
    try
    {
        var parent=object.parentNode.parentNode;
        var day = parent.getElementsByName("day")[0];
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Here i am getting error saying that HTMLTableRowElement does not have method called getElementsByName. Any other way?

Comment: your question seems a bit messed up. this looks like you are getting the tr element instead of the select. I think you'll be better off using jquery as well. now, what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try getting all select elements, looping through them and checking their name:

```
var parent = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
var selects = parent.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    if (selects[i].name == "day") {
        // selects[i] is the target
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's similar to what document.getElementsByName() does but not searching by tag first.

Comment: Glad it worked! Just remember that if you have multiple elements with the name "day" (or whatever), the for loop won't stop at the first one found. If you want it to stop searching at the first one found, put "break;" at the end of the if statement. This is probably unnecessary since you have a small section and probably wouldn't have more than one with the same name, but it could alleviate some extra processing.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular question, you shouldn't access the DOM elements by its name, instead you should access them by its id.

```
foo = document.getElementById("someID"); //Its unique
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByName() method accesses all elements with the specified name.

As you given different name for each select you can access it directly.

```
var x=document.getElementsByName("day");
```

no need of parent